# Auto expand textarea to north

Tags: javascript, html, css

I don't know how to explain it well but I'm trying to build a textarea that auto expand with the text, but all the examples that I find, the text area growth downward, I want the textarea to grow upward.

Examples:

```js
var observe;
if (window.attachEvent) {
  observe = function(element, event, handler) {
    element.attachEvent('on' + event, handler);
  };
} else {
  observe = function(element, event, handler) {
    element.addEventListener(event, handler, false);
  };
}

function init() {
  var text = document.getElementById('text');

  function resize() {
    text.style.height = 'auto';
    text.style.height = text.scrollHeight + 'px';
  }
  /* 0-timeout to get the already changed text */
  function delayedResize() {
    window.setTimeout(resize, 0);
  }
  observe(text, 'change', resize);
  observe(text, 'cut', delayedResize);
  observe(text, 'paste', delayedResize);
  observe(text, 'drop', delayedResize);
  observe(text, 'keydown', delayedResize);

  text.focus();
  text.select();
  resize();
}
```

```css
textarea {
  border: 0 none white;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
  outline: none;
  background-color: #D0D0D0;
  resize: none;
}
```

```html
<body onload="init();">
  <textarea rows="1" style="height:1em;" id="text"></textarea>
</body>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/0a9u7h2g/2/

How can I change this code to make this happen?

Comment: it seems to be working as expected, when text is added, the `textarea` height is increasing directed to bottom...

Comment: Did you mean the other way around? That you want it to grow upward, not downward 

Comment: Like others, I see downward growth.  If you want upward growth, use css to pin the bottom of the textarea.

Comment: Yes, I mean the other way around. I correct it in the post now

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you meant that it should grow *upwards*, rather than downwards. By putting your `textarea` in the bottom of it's containing element, it will be forced to grow upwards.

```js
var observe;
if (window.attachEvent) {
  observe = function(element, event, handler) {
    element.attachEvent('on' + event, handler);
  };
} else {
  observe = function(element, event, handler) {
    element.addEventListener(event, handler, false);
  };
}

function init() {
  var text = document.getElementById('text');

  function resize() {
    text.style.height = 'auto';
    text.style.height = text.scrollHeight + 'px';
  }
  /* 0-timeout to get the already changed text */
  function delayedResize() {
    window.setTimeout(resize, 0);
  }
  observe(text, 'change', resize);
  observe(text, 'cut', delayedResize);
  observe(text, 'paste', delayedResize);
  observe(text, 'drop', delayedResize);
  observe(text, 'keydown', delayedResize);

  text.focus();
  text.select();
  resize();
}
```

```css
textarea {
  border: 0 none white;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
  outline: none;
  background-color: #D0D0D0;
  resize: none;
  width: 100px;
}

body {
  height: 90vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<body onload="init();">
  <textarea rows="1" style="height:1em;" id="text"></textarea>
</body>
```